# R: dplyr "must be a 1d atomic vector or a list" error when using filter_()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` in R called `possibleVotes` which looks like this (see end of post for code that generated this data frame, or CSV table [here](https://pastebin.com/tfz4VM37)):

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 | Var5 | nSuccesses1 | p1     | use1 |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| 0    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 0    | 0           | 0.0225 | 0    |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| 1    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 0    | 1           | 0.1275 | 0    |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| 0    | 1    | 0    | 1    | 0    | 1           | 0.1275 | 0    |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 0    | 1    | 0    | 2           | 0.7225 | 1    |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+--------+------+
```

I'm trying to use `dplyr` to filter it with code like this:

```
round <- 1
roundTotal <- 2

pRound1 <- possibleVotes %>%
    select_(num_range("Var", 1:2), paste0("nSuccesses", round), paste0("p", round), paste0("use", round)) %>%
    distinct_() %>%
    filter_(paste0("nSuccesses", round) == roundTotal & paste0("use", round) == 1) %>%
    select_(paste0("p", round)) %>%
    sum()
```

My expected results is simply that `pRound1` would be 0.7225. Unfortunately I get this error:

> Error: Column `p1` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

I went through each step and discovered that:

1. There is no error up and through `distinct_()`.
2. The error shows up at the `filter_()` step.
3. `num_range()` did not work (the columns `Var1` and `Var2` were not selected)

I have no idea what the error means, and don't know why `num_range()`  did not give me the desired results either...

How do I troubleshoot this? Thanks!

EDIT: After generous help from @Axeman, I tried this for `filter_()`:

```
filter_(lazyeval::interp(~a == b, a = as.name(paste0("nSuccesses", round)), b = roundTotal)) %>% 
filter_(lazyeval::interp(~a == b, a = as.name(paste0("use", round)), b = 1))
```

Unfortunately it still gives this:

> Error: Column `p1` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

EDIT 2: I'm running dplyr 0.5.0 with R 3.4.0.

EDIT 3: Here is the complete code I used to generate the original `possibleVotes` data frame:

```
possibleVotes <- expand.grid(replicate(5, c(0,1), simplify = FALSE))

pSpecies <- 0.85
round <- 1
roundFor <- 2
roundAgainst <- 0
roundTotal <- roundFor + roundAgainst

possibleVotes[paste0("nSuccesses", round)] <- rowSums(possibleVotes[1:roundTotal])
possibleVotes[paste0("p", round)] <- pSpecies^(possibleVotes[paste0("nSuccesses", round)]) * (1-pSpecies)^(round1Total - possibleVotes[paste0("nSuccesses", round)])

possibleVotes[paste0("use", round)] <- apply(possibleVotes, 1, function(x) if (sum(x[1:roundTotal]) == roundFor) 1 else 0)
```

Comment: Those kinds of tables are basically deliberately hard to read in. It's useful to also provide some code to generate that, or to give a `dput`.

Comment: Also I would advise against using `paste` to build calls. See `vignette('nse')`

Comment: @Axeman I don't know how to use `dput` but I've uploaded the data.frame in CSV format here (and edited the post): https://pastebin.com/tfz4VM37   As for using `paste()`, it's because I'd like to dynamically select columns instead of hard-coding them, is there another way to do that??

Comment: See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), and (again) see `vignette("nse")`

Comment: @Axeman Thanks. I tried `vignette("nse")` which led to `vignette("lazyeval")` but I'm completely baffled by them and am even more confused... I don't even get what "standard evaluation" and "quoting" means. Is there another approach to this?

Comment: Use `~num_range("Var", 1:2)` instead of `num_range("Var", 1:2)` (note the `~`). For the `filter` condition, you'll need to build up the call `lazyeval::interp`. Something like: `filter_(lazyeval::interp(~a == b, a = as.name(paste0("nSuccesses", round)), b = roundTotal))`?

Comment: Thank you @Axeman for your patience. I tried it (and added it to the original post), but still get the same error message... What am I missing? (but adding `~` to `num_range()` worked, thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple trick is to `paste0` all the things together to create a condition, freeing from otherwise troublesome condition building process. You could build a condition like this: `paste0("nSuccesses", round, "==", roundTotal, "&", "use", round, "== 1")` it will give you something like `"nSuccesses1==2&use1== 1"`, and just `filter_` that.

Edit: all of my code:

```
dmatrix <- t(matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0.0225,0,
                    1,0,0,1,0,1,0.1275,0,
                    0,1,0,1,0,1,0.1275,0,
                    1,1,0,1,0,2,0.7225,1), nrow = 8, ncol = 4))
possibleVotes <- data.frame(dmatrix)
colnames(possibleVotes) <- c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4","Var5","nSuccesses1","p1","use1")

round <- 1
roundTotal <- 2

pRound1 <- possibleVotes %>%
    select_(~num_range("Var", 1:2), paste0("nSuccesses", round), paste0("p", round), paste0("use", round)) %>%
    distinct_() %>%
    filter_(paste0("nSuccesses", round, "==", roundTotal, "&", "use", round, "== 1")) %>%
    select_(paste0("p", round)) %>%
    sum()
```

Comment: Thank you @Consistency!! Unfortunately even after running your suggestion verbatim I still get the same error message..... Does this suggest another issue?

Comment: The code works for me and get the desired result, I will paste all my code and you can check that.

Comment: @hpy I uploaded all of my code, and it works for me. You can check if there is anything different.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes your code worked for me, too. So I guess it is indeed another problem? I've edited my original post with my code that generated the original data frame, but I can't see why it wouldn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: @hpy It turns out that your problem may be related to that `p1` is actually a `matrix` instead of `vector`. It can be solved by `as.vector`. `possibleVotes[paste0("p", round)] <- as.vector(pSpecies^(possibleVotes[paste0("nSuccesses", round)]) * (1-pSpecies)^(roundTotal - possibleVotes[paste0("nSuccesses", round)]))`. And I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: That solved it!! Thank you so much for your patience and amazing insight. I don't see how I could ever have thought of `matrix` vs `vector` issue without your help. Very grateful. :)

Comment: @hpy You are welcome. And you can use `class(df[,"Var1"])` to check the class of column of your data frame, like whether they are matrix, numeric, etc.

Comment: @Consistency Use the str function.